# How to get all maven dependencies using aether?

Tags: maven, aether

I'm trying to fetch a maven artifact's dependencies using aether. I see a RepositorySystem.collectDependencies(), but that fetches only compile and runtime scoped dependencies. How do I fetch all dependencies for the artifact, including test and provided?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [jcabi-aether](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aether/index.html) (I'm a developer), which is a wrapper around Sonatype Aether:

```
File repo = this.session.getLocalRepository().getBasedir();
Collection<Artifact> deps = new Aether(this.getProject(), repo).resolve(
  new DefaultArtifact("junit", "junit-dep", "", "jar", "4.10"),
  JavaScopes.RUNTIME
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using `DefaultRepositorySystemSession` you may do the following:

```java
defaultRepositorySystemSession.setDependencySelector(new DependencySelector() {
    @Override
    public boolean selectDependency(Dependency dependency) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public DependencySelector deriveChildSelector(DependencyCollectionContext context) {
        return this;
    }
});
```

and then

```java
CollectResult result = repositorySystem.collectDependencies(defaultRepositorySystemSession, request);
```

[Here is an example project that does this.](https://github.com/ivarref/collect-provided-dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

These three files:

https://github.com/terraframe/Runway-SDK/tree/v1.8.0/runwaysdk-server/src/main/java/com/runwaysdk/business/generation/maven

Are a working, stand-alone, example using Aether.

It worked for a few months then I all of a sudden had an issue pop up where it would sometimes on Mac JRE throw a DependencyResolutionException on com.sun:tools.jar.

Good luck, if you decide to use it, I'm instead going to use maven-dependency-plugin `dependency:build-classpath`.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize `DependencyFilter` in Eclipses Aether. A [complete version](https://github.com/eclipse/aether-demo/blob/master/aether-demo-snippets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/aether/examples/ResolveTransitiveDependencies.java) for a sample below can be found in this awesome set of [Aether snippets.](https://github.com/eclipse/aether-demo/find/master)

```
DependencyFilter classpathFilter = DependencyFilterUtils.classpathFilter(JavaScopes.COMPILE, JavaScopes.PROVIDED);

CollectRequest collectRequest = new CollectRequest();
collectRequest.setRoot( new Dependency( artifact, JavaScopes.COMPILE ) );
collectRequest.setRepositories(repositories);

DependencyRequest dependencyRequest = new DependencyRequest( collectRequest, classpathFilter );

List<ArtifactResult> artifactResults =
    system.resolveDependencies( session, dependencyRequest ).getArtifactResults();
```

**UPDATE**

Version 0.9.0M3 is not compatible with Maven 3.1.0, so don't use it inside Maven, i.e. in a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this github project: https://github.com/Gemba/mvn-dd

It downloads all dependencies including test and provided.

It uses aether's library to fetch them.